# How to write a versatile or flexible function that could take any number of parameters in order to perform the specified task on them?

Tags: c++, function

I want to write a function that could take any number parameters when called in main or other classes/functions to be able to perform the operation within it, on custom amount of integers each time.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
int add(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "3 + 4 + 5 = " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return x + y + z;
}
```

Doesn’t link. The compiler will match the forward declared prototype of add to the function call to add() in main(). However, no add() function that takes two parameters was ever implemented (we only implemented one that took 3 parameters), so the linker will complain. the expected result is that the function does not face this issue,without having to write a different function each time for different set of parameters in order to perform operations on them.

Comment: Here's a nice example of doing exactly that: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html The problem is that it doesn't know how many parameters it gets, so the amount of parameters would also have to be a parameter, or you could use a sentinel value, such as always ending with `0`.

Comment: You can use an ellipsis (`...`) or variadic template parameters.

Comment: Several options: take a `std::vector` as argument and operate on the elements it contains, use a `std::initializer_list`, use a variadic template. And more.

Comment: Thanks you all, I was not familiar with variadic templates. I'll look into them.

Comment: maybe you want to use template `template<class... _Args>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP mentioned that he uses C++17, there is a simpler way to do it using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
auto add(Args... args)
{ 
    return (args + ...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "3 + 4 = " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    std::cout << "3 + 4 + 5 = " << add(3, 4, 5) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for simpler solution. I'm always looking for maximum efficiency in coding.

Answer (score 7):

you need to define 2 instances of your `add()` function: one variadic templated and one to terminate unrolling the args;

```
int add(int x) { return x; }        // to terminate templated add

template<typename... Args>
int add(int first, Args... rest)    // to unroll args
 { return first + add(rest...);  }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "3 + 4 = " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    std::cout << "3 + 4 + 5 = " << add(3, 4, 5) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 + 4 = 7
3 + 4 + 5 = 12
```

you would need c++11 or higher for that solution.

Comment: yes, thank you, it works perfectly, I use c++17. thanks again.

Comment: ahh, the crown is stolen for not following-up the comment timely ))))) @Timo: good job! )))))